# If I use CloudCode's httpRequest for a resource that has cache-control set to "private" will it restrict its access to your CloudCode clients?

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, private, cache-control, parse-cloud-code

From my understanding if a `cache-control` header set to `private` it wont allow proxys to send data to it's clients. The request would have to go straight from server to client. So my question is this true for CloudCode i.e does CloudCode act like a proxy in this case where I wont be able to send the data into my app if its HTTP request is being made in cloudcode

Answer (score 0):

`Cache-Control: private` states that the server's response is intended for a specific user, as in, a proxy server shouldn't (MUST NOT) cache this response and serve it to another user.

For example **Alice** accesses `http://example.com/profile` with her authentication info, a proxy server shouldn't blindly serve the same content to **Bob** when he accesses `http://example.com/profile` as he would see **Alice**'s profile (this is the idea behind hardcore REST, in which `/profile` would redirect each user to their own `/profile/{user_id}` which could in turn be cached). I'm not an expert on proxy servers but I believe this is the general idea.

This is intended for proxy server implementations, and I believe you really shouldn't worry about this and think in the context of your application domain. You're not giving details about why and how you're using the downloaded data (returning it straight from a Cloud Function call like an actual proxy, parsing and creating `ParseObject`s from the data, etc.) so I can't really comment further.

Your primary concern should be violating the target domain's Terms of Use/EULA or consuming it's bandwidth (accidental Denial of Service attack!).